# Probability of selecting a particular subset of a set of possible binary choices

Tags: probability

Given 52 individuals making a binary choice of yes or no, what is the probability that the yes choices will be either zero or evenly divisible by 13? Further, what is the probably that that will happen over eight choices each?

With no training in probability (and no particular talent in math), I've gotten as far as the idea that there are $2^{52}$ possible combinations of votes, and that there's only one way to have zero yeses and one to have all yeses. Beyond that, I'm getting lost. How many combinations would there be of 13 yeses and 39 noes, for example?

Finally, if the chances of meeting the criteria for one iteration were $1/x$, does that mean that the chances of the same happening through eight iterations is $1/x^8$?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Thanks, wasn't sure how to do that. Let me have a go.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos That looks better. Now, is the convention to enclose whole numbers in text (e.g. the 42 at the beginning of the post) with dollar signs as well, or leave them in plain text as I have them now?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos angryavian's answer answers my question. Put them in dollar signs as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have gotten to the root of the problem: counting the number of valid combinations, and then dividing by $2^{52}$.

The number of ways to choose a subset of $k$ questions out of $n$ total questions is
$$\binom{n}{k} = \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}.$$
See the Wikipedia articles on [binomial coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient) and [factorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial) if you are unfamiliar with this terminology/notation.
Note that $\binom{n}{0} = \binom{n}{n} = 1$, which matches your intuition that there is only one way to have zero yeses and only one way to have all yeses.

So the final probability you seek is
$$\frac{\binom{52}{0} + \binom{52}{13} + \binom{52}{26} + \binom{52}{39} + \binom{52}{52}}{2^{52}}.$$

Your last sentence is also correct: if you want the probability that this entire thing happens $8$ times, you can raise the above probability to the $8$th power.

Comment: I did indeed have a typo; the first number should have been 52. Sorry for that.

Comment: Followup question: if a "subset of $k$ questions" means a set that is less than the entire set, then if we want to allow for the possibility of selecting the entire set, would we further add ${52 \choose 52}$, or 1, to the possible choices, and then divide the result by $2^{42}$?

Comment: @BobRodes divide by $2^{52}$, but otherwise yes. I've edited my answer.

Comment: Ouch. Exactly. $2^{52}$. Thank you!

Comment: I was able to write a short computer program that applies this formula correctly. I very much appreciate your help! Thanks again.